# How Can I Have All Uploaded Files Be Displayed Back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I had made a project in ASP.NET to which you can upload, download, delete, and preview files. Whenever I upload them (as an admin) I upload them by category, so that whenever the user is on the site and wants to view a specific file that should be placed in a specific category, he should click that category first to have the specific file displayed. Problem is: when you log in to the site as a normal user, at first, ALL files are displayed, and then, you can choose the category and only the files from that category is displayed. What can I do in case if I want to have all the files displayed back, like in the first instance? For example, to have a "show all" button to press so you can re-see what is displayed at the very beginning, before clicking on any other category.

```
@model IEnumerable<Proiect2PracticaClona.Models.Files>

<center>
    <h1>Suntem fericiti</h1>
    <h2>Ca ne merge proiectu</h2>
    <hr />
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))

    {
        <form methord="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
            <input type="file" name="fifile" />
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "incepator")
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "intermediar")
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "admin")
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            <hr />
        </form>}
    <div>
        File Name:<input id="search"  onkeyup="search()" placeholder="cauta"/>

    </div>

    <table class="table">
        
        
           
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Incepator", "Index", "Home", new { id = "incepator" })</li>
                        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Intermediar", "Index", "Home", new { id = "intermediar" })</li>
                        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Home", new { id = "admin" })</li>
                    </ul>
                    
        
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/Home/DocumentViewer/@item.info">@item.info</a></td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("Download","Home",new { filename=item.info })">Download</a></td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { id = item.id })">Delete</a></td>
                }
                
                
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    @section scripts
{
        <script>
            function search() {
                $("tr").each(function (index, value) {
                    if (index > 0 && !$(this).find("td")[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes($("#search").val().toLowerCase())) {
                        $(this).attr("hidden", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr("hidden");
                    }
                    console.log(value);
                })
            }
        </script>
    }
</center>
```

Comment: Is this the category filter being sent to the server?  `@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Home", new { id = "admin" })`  If so then what stops you from having an "all" filter, or no filter at all?  Where is your `Index` action method and what doesn't work when you try to display all records?

Comment: Aside: `<form methord="post" ` do you have it spelled like that in the real thing?

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element is obsolete in HTML5 and was deprecated in HTML4.